# mongodb add a common tag for a batch of documents

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have 1000 documents in a collection and 100 of them belongs to the same book. I want to add a tag for this book.

Is there a better way than adding a tag field to each of 100 documents? Is it possible for me to just save the tag one time and avoid redundancy

Comment: Save the tag in different collection and reference the book id or something.

Comment: But wouldn't that contradict the idea of not normalising table in mongodb? And that also means I have to keep the relationship of two collections in my code. @Veeram

Comment: It will and redundant data is okay in mongodb. So you should be able to tag all the book fields.Alternatively, You will need some key to know what books go against each tag and you can keep the information as separate document in same collection or in different collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually made a document as cover for books and it contains a tags field for array of string. Then I use aggregation to match the tags from that cover document when people want info about a specific book.